# How to handle props navigation inside of if condition using React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have question regarding on props navigation, I was wondering how can i navigate other screen if condition is true? I have module where the user need to login, I am using ReactJS api. Moving forward, I can get the right response in the api, however there is problem on my if statement that **my props is undefined is not an object.**

**I have here my codes that I made,**

```
    AsyncStorage.getItem('authorization_code', (err, result) => {
      let token = result;
      axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'http://1xx.xx.x.xx:8002/api/auth/me?token=',
          headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${token}`}
      }).then(response => {
          const email = response.data.email;
          const user_type = response.data.user_type;

          AsyncStorage.setItem('USERMAIL',email.toString());
          AsyncStorage.setItem('USERTYPE',user_type.toString());

          if(user_type == 1) {
            this.props.navigation.push('Dashboard');
          }
          else if(user_type == 3) {
            this.props.navigation.push('Dashboard');
          }

      })
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're accessing `this` in another [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).  To fix this, you can store a local variable and access it from within the function passed to `then`.  A common convention is to make a new variable called `that` with the `this` you want to persist to the closure.

```
getItemFromStorage() {

  // this line is the key
  const that = this;

  AsyncStorage.getItem('authorization_code', (err, result) => {
    let token = result;
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://1xx.xx.x.xx:8002/api/auth/me?token=',
        headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${token}`}
    }).then(response => {
        const email = response.data.email;
        const user_type = response.data.user_type;

        AsyncStorage.setItem('USERMAIL',email.toString());
        AsyncStorage.setItem('USERTYPE',user_type.toString());

        // now you can access that to obtain the props
        if(user_type == 1) {
          that.props.navigation.push('Dashboard');
        }
        else if(user_type == 3) {
          that.props.navigation.push('Dashboard');
        }
    })
  });
}
```

More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)